# JTA transaction already rolled back (probably due to a timeout)

Tags: spring, jta

When i start the server in debug mode and debug my code that time this error will come. if i skip the break point means it will work. what can i do?

```
org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: JTA transaction already rolled back (probably due to a timeout)
at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1021)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its normal behavior, if there is timeout (any, 5sec) on transactional method and you debug that context for longer then 5sec, transaction should be timed out with an exception.

You can try to temporary (for debug purpose) exclude configuration which adds `@EnableTransactionManagement`

Just tried to exclude in my spring boot app, debug works well

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class)
```